# How can I improve my sorting algorithm in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I wrote a sorting algorithm in python, but I think it looks pretty bad. How can I make it better and more efficient?

```
#lis is the list you want to sort for smallest to biggest
def sortMin(lis):
  output = []
  listen = lis
  for i in range(len(lis)):
    curNum = lis[0]
    curArr = 0
    for j in range(len(lis)):
      if listen[j] < curNum:
        curNum = listen[j]
        curArr = j
    output.append(curNum)
    listen.pop(curArr)
  return output
```

Edit: I know of the list.sort() function, but I want to make my own.

Comment: If you want to learn, you can try implementing quicksort. If you want to use builtin library, you can use `lst.sort()`

Comment: "How can I make it better and more efficient?" -- by using the built-in `sort`

Answer (score 1):

The are numerous way to do sorting efficiently. The most simplest efficient way that you could do is to use the available sort method in python.

```
lis = ['c', 'a', 'b']
lis.sort() # This will sort the list in ascending order
```

If you want to study sorting algorithms then there are may good books on that subject.

For specifically some ways to sort with python then you could checkout something like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_sorting_algorithms.htm

Comment: I knew of this already but wanted to make my own. Do you have anything I can do to improve my code?

Comment: You should avoid using append, it's better to pre-allocate the space you need or just swap the elements within the original list. All the sorting methods in the link I provided swap the elements within the original array.
Also, you iterate over the full list twice you can reduce that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is another "sort function" that improves performance/
readability over yours (avoiding nested loops).

```
def sortMin(my_list):
    sorted_list = []
    while my_list:
        min_ = my_list [0]
        for x in my_list:
            if x < min_:
                min_= x
        sorted_list.append(min_)
        my_list.remove(min_)
    return sorted_list
```

Test:

```
l = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]    
sortMin(l)
```

result:

```
[-23, -6, -5, 0, 5, 23, 23, 67]
```